# How can I change the appearance of paragraph field in google forms

Tags: google-forms

The paragraph field in Google forms shows only single line. I want to capture input spanning several paragraph. So I want to show it as multiple lines with scrollbar to make it look more intuitive.
Is it possible to that some way?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include format settings for paragraph questions.

Reference

- [Change the theme or font of your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/145737?hl=en)